# Can I change my house later in the game?

Tags: hogwarts-legacy

Once I've chosen my house, is it possible to change my house to a different house later in the game or do I need to start a new game?

Like let's say I've chosen Slytherin as my starting house, but later in the game I decide I don't want to be Slytherin anymore and would rather want to be Gryffindor. Is there a way I can change my house without starting a new game? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, you cannot change your House in Hogwarts Legacy after making your final decision in the House sorting ceremony. If you want to change your House, then you’ll have to make a new character which, luckily, there are multiple save slots available.